# Enable pdf caching in IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, pdf, caching, acrobat

At first, caching didn't work in all browsers. Then I made it work in all browsers but IE (IE8) by adding .pdf extension to the url. Servlet stopped being called after that.

I display pdf file inline on the webpage via EMBED tag that loads the following url:

```
http://localhost:7001/app/viewFile.pdf
```

Which is generated by java servlet with the following headers:

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;");
response.setHeader("Cache-control", "cache,max-age=600");
response.setContentType(mimeType);
response.setContentLength(contentLength);
```

For pdf displaying in all browsers I use Adobe Reader 9.2.0.

How to make it work in IE too? I noticed that IE adds 'Cache-Control: no-cache' header to **request**, whereas Safari, for example, doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said before, the [`cache-control`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) header value `cache` is invalid. Use `public` instead.

As to IE not adhering the server-side cache control rules in the `embed` and `object` elements, this is unfortunately a "feature" of IE. Best what you can do is replacing it by an `iframe` element.

Other headers like `expires`, `last-modified`, `etag` and so on ain't going to help.

Comment: Any link with details?

I tried iframe too long time ago but it didn't help. I will try it today again.

Comment: Cache-control: public,max-age=600
Pragma: public,max-age=600

Moreover, other browsers (tried Safari) stop caching the pdf when it's in iframe.

Comment: Interesting, I created a test case with `iframe` and a `cache-control` of `public,max-age=600` on the header of the PDF file and it works in FF/IE/Chrome/Opera, but indeed fails in Safari.

Comment: IE is unfortunately unpredictable.

Comment: I tried again and it worked. You were right! With iframe, IE sends a different request where "Accept" is different and there is no no-cache in this request :) One problems left -- Safari.

Comment: I create iframe/embed via js now. For Safari, embed is displayed. In IE8 have to do jQuery('iframe.pdfViewer').remove(); Otherwise, white area remains on the page (ajax is on).

Comment: In Windows however, Safari is not caching pdf even via embed tag :S Damn, this problem is so annoying!

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas to look into:

1. I don't think `cache` is a valid `Cache-Control` directive.

   Try using a value of `public` instead, or `private` if that's more appropriate to your content. Check out [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) for more information.
2. Perhaps you're sending more than one
   `Cache-Control` directive?

   Use a tool
   like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or
   [LiveHTTPHeaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) to peek at the
   actual headers your browsers are
   receiving. Make sure they're not
   getting something you don't expect.
   It sounds like you might already be
   doing this though. Also make sure you're not also sending `Pragma: no-cache`.
3. Try setting the 
   `Expires` header in addition to using
   `Cache-Control`.

   It's also possible
   you're sending the browser
   conflicting `Cache-Control`/`Pragma`
   headers and IE chooses to take the
   `Pragma` headers as first priority for whatever backwards reason.
4. Make sure IE is configured to allow caching! :)

   `Control Panel` >
   `Internet Options` >
   `Temporary Internet Files` >
   `Settings` >
   `Check for newer versions of stored pages`
5. Try sending the PDF as a response to a `POST` request (via form submit).

   IE is allowing a cache to take place regardless of the headers in the response due to this requirement from [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html): "By default, a response is cacheable if the requirements of the request method, request header fields, **and** the response status indicate that it is cacheable." Responses to `POST` requests are NOT cacheable, so IE shouldn't include that header in it's request.
6. Try sending the `Content-MD5` and `Last-Modified` headers with consistent values (if they're not already being sent).

   This might help convince IE that the content of the PDF has not changed. I don't think this solution will work, because IE is obviously stubborn, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: Funny thing is that when I set "Never" at "Check for newer versions of stored pages", IE still gets a new version of pdf :S

Comment: I added two more suggestions (5 and 6). I think the 5th one is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one obvious way around the problem is to use URL rewriting. If IE works with .pdf in the extension, use mod_rewrite (Apache) or a similar tool to server-side redirect to the right page, while making the client think that it's indeed requesting a PDF file.

Also: review the HTTP headers that the client is receiving using a tool like Fiddler.

Also: review this older question ([PHP: Force file download and IE, yet again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597732/php-force-file-download-and-ie-yet-again)), I've had similar problems with IE not forcing downloads, too.

Comment: The browser couldn't care less what the extension in the URL is. It's only going to look at the MIME type.

Comment: They are supposed to look at MIME type but they do not (as I said in the question). Although, I am not sure yet whose fault is that: browser's or adobe reader's.