# Mp3 Download not functioning

Tags: php, mp3

I'm offering a sermon downloading site and I have a user experiencing an issue with his download.  Anyone have any ideas on how I can improve this code, or perhaps send better headers...

```
$path = "http://www.domain.com/sermon_files/".date("Y", $array["preached"])."/".$array["filename"];
$corePath = "/home/user/public_html/sermon_files/".date("Y", $array["preached"])."/".$array["filename"];
if (!file_exists($corePath)) {
    echo "An error has occured with this download.";    
} else {
    header("Pragma: public"); // required
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private", false); 
    header("Content-Type: audio/mp3");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$array["title"]."\";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($corePath));
    readfile($path);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: What exact issue are you running into?

Comment: Why not just put a link on the page to the file?

Comment: maybe because you have to be logged to download it or for statistics purpose.

Comment: elaborate on what `$array` contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this thread, I had similar problems: [PHP: Force file download and IE, yet again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597732/php-force-file-download-and-ie-yet-again). Also consider using Fiddler to capture the exact HTTP headers that are being sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Combine your PHP ( ? ) code with a server with X-Send available, [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) has it so does [apache](http://achmadz.blogspot.com/2009/07/using-php-and-apache-modxsendile-x.html)

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for Expires: 0 on downloads. This messes with IE6's tiny little brain and makes it think there is no data to save/open. Try expiring in a minute from access and see if that fixes the problem. Otherwise, tell us exactly what the problem is.