# Javascript JQuery link to download a txt file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to 'force' the browser to download a file instead of opening that?

```
<a href="file.txt">Download this file</a>
```

I've tried the method via js using the window.open("file.txt", "Download");

but no success.

Thx.

Updating:

I've done a php file as follow;

```
<html>
<a href='dl.php?bid=3'>

<php>
$sql="select barquivo from bibilioteca where bid=$_GET[bid]";
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=biblioteca/$row[barquivo]");
```

And it download a file "biblioteca_" with 0 bytes.

Comment: The best answer is on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597732/php-force-file-download-and-ie-yet-again/1597946#1597946

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do this server-side.

If you send a

```
Content-type: application/octet
```

or

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=file.txt
```

header then the user will be prompted to download.

Comment: `octet-stream`, usually. However just `octet` would work too simply due to being an unknown type.

Answer (score 2):

Not at the javascript level. You can have a good deal of control on what the user agent (browser) will attempt to do, by changing the the Mime Type of the content served - that can be done from the web server or server side application.

That means, your ".txt" file is sent to the browser with a

```
Content-Type: text/plain
```

http header.
If instead it is served with:

```
Content-Type: application/octect-stream
```

http header instead, most likely the user will be prompted to save the file
(regardless of the file name or extension)

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done in pure Javascript as far as I know. You have to send the appropriate headers server side.

If you can use Apache´s `.htaccess` settings (much easier) or PHP (more complicated because you'd have to parse txt files through PHP, or introduce a PHP script to pass through the files), you can refer to the accepted answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465573/forcing-to-download-a-file-using-php).

Answer (score 1):

It's up to the server to [send the appropriate header](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1806.txt).

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=schmoo.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

For those looking to d/l files trhough a link heres the best solution

[PHP: Force file download and IE, yet again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597732/php-force-file-download-and-ie-yet-again/1597946#1597946)

by cballou