# PHP output file on disk to browser

Tags: php

I want to serve an existing file to the browser in PHP.
I've seen examples about image/jpeg but that function seems to save a file to disk and you have to create a right sized image object first (or I just don't understand it :))

In asp.net I do it by reading the file in a byte array and then call context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytearray), so I'm looking for something similar in PHP.

Michel

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is **[fpassthru()](https://www.php.net/fpassthru)** that should do exactly what you need. See the manual entry to read about the following example:

```
<?php

// open the file in a binary mode
$name = './img/ok.png';
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

// send the right headers
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

// dump the picture and stop the script
fpassthru($fp);
exit;

?>
```

See [**here**](http://de.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) for all of PHP's filesystem functions.

If it's a binary file you want to offer for download, you probably also want to send the right headers so the "Save as.." dialog pops up. See the 1st answer to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597732/php-force-file-download-and-ie-yet-again) for a good example on what headers to send.

Comment: What if I already have binary content stored as a variable. How do I output it to the browser as a downloadable file?

Comment: I try doing this with a .svg file (textfile) but the browser downloads a php-file instead of showing svgfile (image) I changed Content-Type to image/svg

Comment: It worked better with Content-Type image/svg+xml but now it complains that xml declaration starts at line 2

Answer (score 16):

I use this

```
  if (file_exists($file)) {


        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I use readfile() ( http://www.php.net/readfile )...

But you have to make sure you set the right "Content-Type" with header() so the browser knows what to do with the file.

You can also force the browser to download the file instead of trying to use a plug-in to display it (like for PDFs), I always found this to look a bit "hacky", but it is explained at the above link.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started:
http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Edit: If your web server supports it, using

```
header('X-Sendfile: ' . $filename);
```

where file name contains a local path like

```
/var/www/www.example.org/downloads/example.zip
```

is faster than readfile().

(usual security considerations for using header() apply)

Answer (score 1):

For both my website and websites I create for clients I use a PHP script that I found a long time ago.

It can be found here: http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/download.php

I use a slightly modified version of it to allow me to obfuscate the file system structure (which it does by default) in addition to not allowing hot linking (default) and I added some additional tracking features, such as referrer, IP (default), and other such data that I might need should something come up.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the script. If i want to expand my first script i'll definately will use it.

Answer (score 1):

Following will initiate XML file output

```
$fp = fopen($file_name, 'rb');

// Set the header
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file_name));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"');

fpassthru($fp);
exit;
```

The ***'Content-Disposition: attachment'*** is pretty common and is used by sites like Facebook to set the right header