# how to export a mysql db table data to a spreadsheet and then send it to the browser?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I need to export a table named 'app_users' from my database, into a spreadsheet, a csv for example. How do I do this? Also, how do I send this file to browser? I am using Zend framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/356605/808532) you could run the following SQL query if you have direct access to the filesystem the db server is on:

```
SELECT *
FROM app_users
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/app_users.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

**EDIT**: You'll probably also need to delete this file using php after it's created and served to the user, otherwise the next time the query above is run it might refuse to overwrite the file (that's the default).

Comment: Thanks Ryan! and how do I send it to the browser so that the user is prompted with a "save" dialog?

Comment: If you're executing this sql command in php on the server, add code after it in php that will serve the file back to the user's browser. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2028918/808532 for an example, although you'll need to change the header types to csv.

Comment: it worked like a charm! Thanks! But, the csv file does not contain any field names in the top row. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately you have to do it manually with a UNION in the query along the lines of `SELECT 'first', 'second', 'third' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM app_users`...see http://www.pressingquestion.com/1528089/Include-Headers-When-Using-Select-Into-Outfile%3F

Comment: also, I am trying to delete this file using unlink(). But since the owner of teh file is mysql, I cannot. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

by clicking export button in mysql toolbar to sql database

Comment: i need to send the file to the browser when a visitor clicks on a download button in my website! :)