# how to install securefiles in silverstripe 3

Tags: silverstripe

i'm trying to install the securefiles module https://github.com/hamishcampbell/silverstripe-securefiles on my silverstripe 3 installation.

After renaming, uploading and dev/build
i get two checkboxes in security>groups>groupname>permissions named Access to Secured Files and Manage File Security Settings.

But that's all. 
and when i want to access the files section in silverstripe i get a server error.

Can someone tell me what i need to modify that secure files is working?

Answer (score 0):

That extension seems to be only compatible with SS2.x so for SS3 you might need to find another extension, update it for 3.x (http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/trunk/changelogs/3.1.0) or try a custom approach like [Silverstripe - google picks links on members only page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733985/silverstripe-google-picks-links-on-members-only-page/16741575#16741575)