# Rails carrierwave S3 get url with Content-Disposition header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

We are using carrierwave + aws S3 to upload file, and we need provide a download function.

For solution 1, we use:

```
= link_to "Download", file.doc.url, download: file.original_name
```

And it does not work under IE8, click the link will open this file(image).

According to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968837/file-opens-instead-of-downloading-in-internet-explorer-in-a-href-link), I should add `Content-Disposition` header,

Then I check aws S3 document, [Found](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html) I need add `response-content-disposition` to `file.doc.url`,

Is there any way I can do this in carrierwave, or I could use other ways? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Got it, for `fu = FileUploader.new`, we can use:

```
fu.url(query: {"response-content-disposition" => "attachment;"})
```

Read tons of documents and source code.