# Rails download file direct from S3 with content-disposition = attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is my controller

**Cotroller**

```
def download
    data = open(@attachment.file.url).read

    @attachment.clicks = @attachment.clicks.to_i + 1
    @attachment.save
    send_data data, :type => @attachment.content_type, :filename => @attachment.name
  end
```

example:

```
@attachment.file.url = "http://my_bucket.cloudfront.net/uploads/attachment/file/50/huge_file.pptx"
```

I did this, but if **@attachement is a huge file** (eg. 300MB), my server crash.
I want to allow users to download the file in the browser directly from my AWS server?

2) tip: Do you suggest to download file from S3 (where they are stored) or with CloudFront?

Comment: Why you not give the @attachment.file.url to user directly? So it won't eat your cpu memory?

Comment: Because I want to track number of clicks. So I have to pass through a controller

Comment: Nginx X-Accel-Redirect is the only way to serve big files. Basically Rails action returns back a file name via HTTP header to Nginx internal location. This location serves through Nginx S3 proxy without any backend. In that case Rails finishes request quickly and not blocked by downloading process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you using carrierwave gem, you can try this to track number of clicks

```
def download
  @attachment.clicks.to_i += 1
  @attachment.save
  redirect_to @attachment.file.url(query: {"response-content-disposition" => "attachment;"})
end
```

references:

- [Rails carrierwave S3 get url with Content-Disposition header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947512/rails-carrierwave-s3-get-url-with-content-disposition-header)