# On web page when you give link to a file, mozilla firex fox shows directory structure like below however in IE new window is opened

Tags: html, file, hyperlink, href, mozilla

On web page when you give link to a file, mozilla firefox shows directory structure like list view but in IE new window is opened when you click on link.

I need to display structure of folder like list view in mozilla on IE browser

Comment: Maybe it is trying to open a new window with the file to download. In this case try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968837/file-opens-instead-of-downloading-in-internet-explorer-in-a-href-link

Comment: I am not trying to download i just want list view of folders to be visible on IR browser I have used 
<a href="file:///C:/Drivers" > my docs</a>

Comment: when you say "display structure of folder" I understand the save as dialog, isn't it?

Comment: Where is the question, as in a sentence with a question mark. Do we need to infer that you cannot fulfil the needs you expressed? Please make that explicit.