# When i click on a hyperlink with txt file reference. I want to download the file instead of opening in new window

Tags: internet-explorer, download, text-files

When i click on the hyperlink of a text file I get an option to save or open the file in chrome and firefox but in IE it directly opens. I want the txt file to save instead of opening in IE browser.

```
    <a href="/documents/mm.txt">Download the file
    </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can right-click and select "Save target as..."

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968940 answers a related question. It looks like it will be difficult or impossible to download without right-clicking. If you are making the website in question, there is a way to change the HTTP headers so that the file will download. Otherwise, unless you are on an old enough version of Windows to have a ["Confirm after download"](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/where-is-confirm-open-after-download-checkbox-for/036e7d8f-50a3-45e5-abd6-7647870b53b2) box in Folder Options, you'll probably just have to right-click.

Comment: Yeah. but i want to download it when i click on it.