# open download file dialog using javascript In IE11

Tags: javascript, download, href, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to show download file dialog using javascript in IE 11.But following code doesn't works for me

```
<a id="downloadLink" href="" target="_blank" onclick='download()'>Download</a>
```

on anchor tag click event download function is called

```
function download() {
          var link = document.getElementById('downloadLink');
          link.href = "data:image/png;base64,abcdefghijklmnop";
          link.download = '/systemcommon/BILL'+document.BankPaymentFile.sysDate.value+'.csv'; 
      }
```

It does not work as in IE 11 it doesn't suppport "download" attribute of anchor element.

Any other way to do this??

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968837/file-opens-instead-of-downloading-in-internet-explorer-in-a-href-link

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394871/download-attribute-on-a-tag-not-working-in-ie as well