# How to write html code for download file supporting IE?

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a code like this:

```
<a href="input.txt" download="output.txt"><button>Download</button></a>
```

But, it only works in Chrome and Firefox. IE doesn't support it.

How to do this in a way that all browsers support it?

Comment: <a href="input.txt" download="output.txt"><button>Download</button></a>

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ It was the bold "Download" in the post. It just wasn't formatted as code.

Comment: Related: [File opens instead of downloading in internet explorer in a href link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968837/file-opens-instead-of-downloading-in-internet-explorer-in-a-href-link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form method="get" action="input.pdf">
    <button type="submit">Download</button>
</form>
```

You could use a button like this for the download.
This wont work in files like txt and images. for forcing download for these files, changes need to made in the server side.

Comment: this code also not support my requirement.Download file not opening file